# chown not working in mounted partition

Tags: linux, mount, chown

I'm using Fedora 24 and I have two partitions. I login as `user` and mount the second partition by clicking on it on the file manager. A window pops up asking for my password so I'm assuming the mount is performed as `root`.

However, all the files in the mounted partition have `user` as the owner, and `chown` doesn't work on them.

```
[root@mypc Downloads]# chown root:root pointer2.txt 
[root@mypc Downloads]# ls -la pointer2.txt 
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 user user 945 Aug  2  2016 pointer2.txt
```

What is the problem here? Is this normal? Can it be fixed?

Here is the relevant output of `cat /proc/mounts` (line break added for clarity):

```
/dev/sda2 /run/media/user/666EF0326EEFF8A7 fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,
group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

Comment: What type of filesystem is in use? Are you performing the `chown` as root?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, I'm running `chown` as root. The filesystem type shows up as `fuseblk`. I don't know what that means, but I'm dual booting, and this is the Windows partition.

Comment: This is probably a non-Unix filesystem like FAT. Add the output of `cat /proc/mounts` to your question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The partition has a non-Unix file system without support for Unix permissions.

The fuse layer decides to give all files 0777 permissions and assigns the user and group of the user who mounted the filesystem to them.

You will not be able to change the permissions or ownership of these files for as long as they reside on that partition.

Comment: And I'm assuming there's no way to change the partition type while keeping the data, unless I backup first and then put the files back after formatting?

Comment: @devil0150 Reformatting the partition with a Unix native filesystem would work (back up files first!), but would likely make it unusable from Windows.